# Cannot use laravel eloquent relationship latest() function to get last value because camel casing

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm getting this error because I'm using camel casing

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at'
```

I already have

```
public static $snakeAttributes = false;
```

on my model.

```
public function lastUser() {
    return $this->hasOne(
        'App\Models\Views\UserView',
        'groupId')->latest();
}

$groups = GroupView::with('lastUser')->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `latest()` method like this:

```
->latest('createdAt');
```

The thing is `created_at` is hardcoded and there is no other way to use `latest()` without overriding the method (which is a bad idea):

```
public function latest($column = 'created_at')
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like charm. Camel casing is such a pain in the ass in laravel.